# How to send currently selected object properties in visual studio to printer for hard-copy listing?

Tags: vb.net, printing

Is there a way to print the properties of an object that is currently selected in a VB project?

Comment: For this I write a report and send the object to the report.  Crystal reports is available for visual studio as well as microsoft reporting.
You can also code your own report using System.Drawing.Printing.  Its very low level and requires you keep track of the layout of each object your are printing.  Its kind of like using a typewriter.

Comment: Thanks for that information Haim. Much appreciated. I am still pretty new to using Visual Studio so not sure how to accomplish that, but at least I have a starting point. :-)